# Can't import pyserial (ImportError No module named pyserial)

Tags: python, python-2.7, importerror, python-2.x, pyserial

I have a script that currently requires Python2 to run. I have a fresh Ubuntu install setup by my IT this morning.

I get this error message when attempting the script: "`ImportError: No module named pyserial`". I tried installing pyserial various ways, with `pip` and `pip3` , `sudo apt-get install pyserial`, with `python2 -m pip install pyserial`. I can install it to the Python2.7 and Python3.8 site-packages.

I'm not sure if it's even installing correctly; when I look into the folder I dont see a .py script. I'm new to python, but I thought all the packages had to have a .py script in them?

[Image of the folder ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyserial-3.5.dist-info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tt9ym.png)

I also tried seeing if I could do anything from the python environment. I go to either python2.7 or 3.8 and I can use `import serial` with no error. `Import pyserial` however sends the same error message as stated above.

I also tried changing the line in my script from `import serial` to `import pyserial as serial`, this also didnt help. Now instead the error message reads "`No module named pyserial`".

I also tried installing older versions of pyserial, with no luck (version 2.6).

Comment: pip install pyserial

Comment: The package is named "pyserial"; the module contained in that package is named "serial". `import serial` is exactly what you should be using here.